# Negative affects of not grounding a usb connection?

Tags: power, usb

I am currently attempting to mod a Nintendo 64 case to house my raspberry pi 3. I want to keep the original controller ports, but the port only has 3 pins. Would wiring a usb cable without the ground wire connected have any adverse affect?

Comment: Imagine a battery with only one terminal. How will you complete the circuit? Where will the electrons come from and where will the electrons flow to?

Comment: Wiring two connectors with disregard to pin functions is not very smart to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a negative effect -- it won't work!

A ground is required as a reference for the USB VBUS line. Without a ground, current cannot flow through the device, so it will not work.

You need all four contacts (GND, VBUS, D+, and D+) to attach a USB device. You can't get away with fewer.

Comment: VBUS isn't necessarily required.

Comment: @MattYoung VBUS is required for a self-powered device to know it has been inserted.